# How to berks update [cookbook] without updating its dependencies?

Tags: berkshelf, berksfile

for example:

```
name             'my_nagios'
version          '2.0.7'

depends 'nagios', '~> 7.2.6'
depends 'nrpe', '~> 1.5.2'
recommends 'python', '~> 1.4.6'
```

now, I did a little change to my_nagios cookbook and I only want to update itself without dependencies such as nagios, nrpe, python, etc. as I am sure that I don't need upgrade dependency cookbook's version.

the following command will return "Resolving cookbook dependencies...", and there is no changes to berksfiel.lock. If I remove the parameters "-o my_nagios", it will update berksfile.lock with all its dependencies.

```
berks update my_nagios -o my_nagios
```

In summary, how to berks update [cookbook] without updating its dependencies? 
Any help will be much appreciated.

p.s. I used Google, but can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock your dependencies to specific versions:

```
depends 'nagios', '7.2.6'
depends 'nrpe', '1.5.2'
recommends 'python', '1.4.6'
```

It isn't best idea, unless upstream cookbooks doesn't follow [semver](http://semver.org/). `~>` means, only bug fix releases should be applied (if maintainer follows semver).